# Using retrofit 2 while doing get request i am getting 404 error but api give response if use postman

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to perform a request using Retrofit but I'm getting 404 error

HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

```
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient= new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @NotNull
                @Override
                public okhttp3.Response intercept(@NotNull Chain chain) throws IOException {

                    Request originalrequest = chain.request();
                 
                    Request newRequest = originalrequest.newBuilder()
                                           .header("Authorization","Bearer tokenvalue")
                            .build();
                    return chain.proceed(newRequest);
                }
            })
            .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
            .build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost/baseurl/v1/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();

   ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
```

Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<>();

```
    headers.put("clientkey", "*****MQ==");

    Call<OrgInfoModel> call = apiInterface.getOrgInf(headers,orgid);

  
    call.enqueue(new Callback<OrgInfoModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<OrgInfoModel> call, retrofit2.Response<OrgInfoModel> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                                    
            } else {

                progressDialog.hide();
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(activityRootView, "Request can't be completed", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                sbView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.color_red));
                TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(R.id.snackbar_text);
                textView.setTextSize(18);

                snackbar.show();
                return;
            }
          }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<OrgInfoModel> call, Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `"Bearer tokenvalue"` where is your token value?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to localhost from an emulator or a device. My guess is, that localhost corresponds to something on your development machine, that is not reachable from the emulator/device.
This would also explain, why it is reachable from Postman (which is also running on the hosting machine)